Seller kept part of my earnest money for no reason
We placed a contract on a property.  We paid earnest money.   We paid for an option period to protect our earnest money. The seller accused the inspector of breaking something on the pool equipment.  The inspector has pictures and nothing is broken. We pulled out because the seller wouldn't agree to fix certain items that were very costly.  The seller only released a portion of our monies stating he would have to repair what the inspector broke.  Is this even legal?  He literally just stole money from us.

Presumably, you're working with lawyers, realtors, etc. that can advise you better than random folks on the internet.  Obviously, the seller is not entitled to money if there was no damage done and you had the right to withdraw from the agreement without losing your earnest money.  You could likely sue in small claims court (or your country's equivalent).

They gave you a reason; you just disagree with it. Unless you want to take it to court there may be little you can do.

What's legal or not depends on jurisdiction. Since you didn't mention location no-one knows. You should really discuss this with an attorney.

Depends on your jurisdiction, depends on the specific terms of your contract, and either way is a specific matter for your personal expert rather than a general matter strangers on the internet should answer. Talk to your realtor. Also consider whether pursuing it is worth (in money and personal satisfaction) the time, money, and effort spent in achieving it. Only you can answer that.

This deal fell through because your side insisted on repairs being made by the seller before closing, and they refused. A different approach for your next go-round with a seller is to ask for a price reduction to cover the cost of needed repairs that were revealed in the inspection. If they refuse the reduction, you refuse the purchase under the terms of the contract. No butting heads, and you get your earnest money back. An allegedly broken pool item is a non-issue for the seller if you're buying it. (If a mortgage lender insists on repairs before closing, this tactic is not feasible.)
